# Oracle SQL Find Highest ID Across All Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

Every one of my tables has an "id" field.  I need to be able to find the highest ID across all of them, given that the list of tables might change.

Is there any way to get the list of tables in an oracle database, aggregate their rows (only ids), and then get the `max()`?

P.S. This is for updating a sequence which has gone out of whack.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is some simple dynamic SQL driving off the data dictionary:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2      l_id pls_integer;
  3      max_id pls_integer;
  4      max_tab_name varchar2(30);
  5  begin
  6      max_id := 0;
  7      for r in ( select table_name
  8                 from user_tab_columns
  9                 where column_name = 'ID' )
 10      loop
 11          execute immediate 'select max(id) from '||r.table_name
 12              into l_id;
 13          if l_id > max_id
 14          then
 15              max_id := l_id;
 16              max_tab_name := r.table_name;
 17          end if;
 18      end loop;
 19      dbms_output.put_line('Highest score = '||max_id||' table='||max_tab_name);
 20  end;
 21  /
Highest score = 2010070705 table=SESSIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If the sequence services tables across several schemas, you will need to drive off ALL_TAB_COLUMNS and include OWNER in the query.

Comment: I initially got a `ORA-01426: numeric overflow`, but I changed the l_id and max_id types to `numeric` inline with my ID column and this worked perfectly. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
 SELECT MAX(ID) 
 FROM
 (
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM CUSTOMER
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM EMPLOYEE
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM MANAGER
 );
```

Repeat the UNION ALL for all tables that you need to search from.

Comment: That's very close, but I'm looking for a statement that will still work if I add more tables and wont need to be updated each time one is added.  Is there any way?

Answer (score -1):

how about querying the sequence that drives the id's for CURRVAL...

if you need to find out also what table that id is in, then construct a new table to track the id centrally and add triggers to populate on insert.

Comment: p.s. i sincerely hope you are using a sequence and not asking this because you want to increment the id for the next insert...

Comment: It's for updating a sequence!

Comment: if it is an oracle sequence, then this is a one time effort, and you do not need to manage new or changing tables.  if it is your own sequence, then convert to an oracle sequence instead :)

Comment: CURRVAL only works for a session which has already invoked the sequence through a NEXTVAL call.  We can get the current bound of a sequence with `select last_number from user_sequences`.  However, that won't help in a scenario where something has not been using the sequence to assign a primary key value (say a bulk data load process).  Then routines using the sequence will generate collisions.  I think that is the situation here.